# No Instance(s) Found when remotely getting a list of installed programs

Tags: windows, command-prompt, wmic

When I run my batch file, I'll type in the computer's name, then type the name of the program I'm looking for. I have added the "name like '(word)%'" part so it doesn't need an exact match to find a program. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
set /p name="Enter PC Name: "
set /p prgm="Type Part of the Program Name: "
wmic /node:%name% product where "name like '%prgm%%'" get name,version
set /p fprgm="Enter Full Program Name: "
wmic /node:%name% product where name="%fprgm%" call uninstall
pause
```

If I go into WMIC manually and search using the `/node:(pc-name) product where "name like '(word)%'" get name,version` it works. But running the code above does not; instead it returns

> No Instance(s) Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape some characters with special meaning](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) so they are interpreted literally.

To treat a percent sign (`%`) as a regular character in a batch script,  *double* it (`%%`) as in next example:

```
==>type 29951224.bat
@ECHO ON >NUL
@SETLOCAL

set "name=localhost"
set "prgm=visual F"
wmic /node:%name% product where "name like '%prgm%%%'" get name,version

==>29951224.bat

==>set "name=localhost"
==>set "prgm=visual F"
==>wmic /node:localhost product where "name like 'visual F%'" get name,version
Name               Version
Visual F# 3.1 SDK  12.0.21005
Visual F# 3.1 VS   12.0.21005

==>
```